# Handling exceptions inside Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, error-handling

I wonder if its normal practice to write such kind of code in wpf application, so that i can catch exceptions and show some message on the UI:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{                                              
    try
    {
        if (AuthenticationManager.Instance.Authenticate(username, password))
        {
            ... 
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Failed");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => txtWarning.Text = ex.Message));
    }
});
```

So this code will show error message on UI thread. If this is "OK" then why everyone suggests to use `t.Wait();` and then catch all the exceptions that appeared in task?
PS, may be question is silly, but i didnt find proper explanation and am new to using of Tasks.

**Update**
[This Joe Albahari's](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism) article helped me in understanding tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TPL makes a great effort to process exceptions for you and move them outside your Task(s).

So while you can catch them in the Task itself, that should be the exception to the rule.

In general you will indeed want to handle exceptions around the Wait point. In the case of showing messages on the GUI that eliminates the Dispatch problem immediately.

Comment: But if i use Wait doesnt that mean that the UI will freeze(for example i have UI with some background work), wait for bw to finish, handle bw's exceptions and continue only after that..? That seems to break all the async work im expecting from another thread. I think im mistaking, but thats how i understand the Wait method :(

Comment: @0x49D1: but if you already got an exception in other thread, this thread, even if not yet interopped, by the way already is in not "valid state", so you have to break it's execution, isn't it?

Comment: @Tigran, yes, and i will break/cancel it..Cant i?!

Comment: It's not intended like a good practise to Abort a thread, if it's got an exception, it will be go away by itself (should at least :))

Comment: Ok :), but i have asked about handling thread exceptions inside thread and loggin/passing them to UI asynchroneusly. The solution i posted-works(think it works fine), so i asked why msdn suggests to "trigger" exceptions using Wait, tho Wait makes UI actually WAIT for other thread to finish(tho as ive already said, i can be mistaken)..

Comment: @Henk Holterman, can i ask you again about same thing..? What can you say about such approach: Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{...}).ContinueWith(task =>
                                          {
                                              if (task.Exception != null)
                                              { //*Code to handle exceptions even in UI thread..*//}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());  ? Thank you.